# Getting attachment's hash for .msg files

Tags: python, outlook

Right now, I have code that does the following

1. Gets emails from inbox
2. Downloads emails
3. Goes through every email that was downloaded, and extracts the attachments
4. Saves the attachment
5. Gets the hash for the file that was saved

But instead of saving the attachment, is it possible to just get the hash for the attachment, and skipping the save?

```
attachments = message.Attachments
for attachment in attachments:
    if attachment.FileName.endswith(".msg"):
        attachment.SaveASFile(
            os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/attachments/' + str(
                time.time()) + "-" + message.subject + "-" + attachment.FileName)
```

EDIT:

This is what I've tried:

```
def get_attachments(message):
    attachments = message.Attachments
    for attachment in attachments:
        data_array = message.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102")
        print len(data_array)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, u'Microsoft Outlook', u'The property "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102" is unknown or cannot be found.', None, 0, -2147221233), None)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You need to use the [PropertyAccessor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachment.propertyaccessor.aspx) property of the Attachment class to get an instance of the corresponding class. It returns a [PropertyAccessor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863046.aspx) object that supports creating, getting, setting, and deleting properties of the parent Attachment object. So, you can use the GetProperty method of the PropertyAccessor class to get a value of the PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN property (the DASL name is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102`) which returns a byte array which represents the attached file.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting a weird error out of this, will edit my question to reflect my feedback.

Comment: What Outlook version do you have installed on the PC? The fact is that PropertyAccessor didn't allow to get huge values in old Outlook versions. You need to use a low-level API - Extended MAPI or any other wrappers around that API (such as Redemption).

Comment: Did you check out the the Type property before getting the PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN property value?

Answer (score 0):

PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN will only be available for the regular by-value attachments. Embedded message or OLE attachments do not have that property. Make sure Attachment.Type property == 1 (OlAttachmentType.olByValue).

In case of an embedded message attachment, you can save it as to temporary MSG file and calculate its hash, but note that the MSG file will include a date/time stamp, and that will result in a new hash value each time the MSG file is saved.